# how can I check if two directory are in the same partition in ubuntu

Tags: 10.04, partitioning, mount

I forget whether I have mounted `/` and `/boot` to the same partition in my ubuntu 10.04. What command can I use to check it out? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `df`. It will give you the free space per partition and also its mount point.

Answer (score 1):

Use the mount command itself.  You can pipe through grep to de-clutter if necessary:

```
me@banshee:~$ mount | egrep 'on /(boot)? '
/dev/mapper/banshee-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdc1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
```

Comment: You're welcome - please mark the question as "answered" by accepting whichever of the two answers you preferred. :)